# df says zero 1k-blocks free but copying still possible (3 TB ext4)

Tags: space, hard-drive, linux-disk-free

I have 3 TB internal harddisks which are (apparently) almost full. Df says 0 1k-blocks free but I can still copy a file of more than 200 Mb to the drive. What is wrong here?

Comment: Are you doing this as root?

Comment: As root gives the same output, see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ext4 keeps 5% of the disk as reserved space by default to prevent fragmentation. This space is not available to normal users but can be used by root. This is also why the equality
`Total = Used + Available`
doesn't hold when you look at the `df` output for an ext4 filesystem.

Try the following experiment.

```
$ fallocate -l 100M image.raw
$ mkfs.ext4 image.raw
$ sudo losetup -f image.raw
$ sudo mount /dev/loop0 /mnt
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/file bs=512
dd: error writing ‘file’: No space left on device
```

The filesystem should have 95k total blocks, 0 available and about 88k used.
If you then try doing the same as root

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/file2 bs=512
```

then you should be able to fill it up some more, up to about 93k blocks used.